# ScalaTest Matchers vs MustMatchers difference

Tags: scala, scalatest, matcher

It seems for latest version of ScalaTest we have two matchers one is`Matchers` (ShouldMatchers before) and`MustMatchers`.

What's the real difference between this two? Is that kind of style the team can choose or?

Also, any difference between`shouldBe` and `should be`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only difference is the word - quoting from t[he ScalaDocs for `MustMatcher`](http://doc.scalatest.org/2.2.4/index.html#org.scalatest.MustMatchers):

> Trait `MustMatchers` is an alternative to `Matchers` that provides the exact same meaning, syntax, and behavior as `Matchers`, but uses the verb must instead of should. The two traits differ only in the English semantics of the verb: should is informal, making the code feel like conversation between the writer and the reader; must is more formal, making the code feel more like a written specification.

As for `should be` vs. `shouldBe` ... it depends on which instance of `should[Be]` you are invoking.  In all cases `shouldBe` does one less registration step (because it skips the work that `be` does).  Sometimes it looks like that means fewer objects are allocated - other times, the same steps are taken, but both "should" and "be" are registered in one pass.  As far as I can tell there is no difference in *behavior* (at least in the day-to-day of writing tests), it's just which one you prefer stylistically.